# CameraKitView library is not getting initialized with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera

I am trying to setup `CameraKitView`. I followed the docs, but my `CameraKitView` in my Activity is not getting initialized. I have tried to initialize the `CameraKitView` in different ways without any luck.
My XML looks like the following:

```
<com.camerakit.CameraKitView
   android:id="@+id/camerakit"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="400dp"
   android:adjustViewBounds="true"
   android:keepScreenOn="true"
   app:camera_flash="auto"
   app:camera_facing="back"
   app:camera_focus="continuous"
   app:camera_permissions="camera"/>
```

My activity looks like that:

```
class CameraActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var camerakitview: CameraKitView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera)
        camerakitview = findViewById<CameraKitView>(R.id.camerakit)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        camerakitview.onStart()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        camerakitview.onResume()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        camerakitview.onPause()
        super.onPause()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        camerakitview.onStop()
        super.onStop()

    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        camerakitview.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    }
}
```

The error looks like the following:

> UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property camerakitview has not been initialized

What did I overlook?

EDIT: I tried the same code in a Java Class instead of Kotlin. That way the camera works.

Comment: have you tried using `findViewById(R.id.camerakit) as CameraKitView`

Comment: I have just tried. It is the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I used the method:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?)
```

Instead of:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
```

Answer (score 0):

for using **CameraKitView** in the **kotlin** you need to call methods in **coroutine** like this.

```
//onstart
    GlobalScope.launch {
                runBlocking {
                    binding.cameraKitView.onStart()
                }
            }
    //onresume
    GlobalScope.launch {
                runBlocking {
                    binding.cameraKitView.onResume()
                }
            }

//onstop
    GlobalScope.launch {
                runBlocking {
                    binding.cameraKitView.onStop()
                }
            }

//onPause
    GlobalScope.launch {
                runBlocking {
                    binding.cameraKitView.onPause()
                }
            }
```

***that's the reason for adding the coroutine with this library.***

**Same for Capturing Image**

```
//Capture image
            GlobalScope.launch {
            runBlocking {
                binding.camera.captureImage { cameraKitView, bytes ->
//do your stuff here
                }
            }
        }
```